# A moose around method modifier applies to several attributes, how do I tell which attribute is being modified?

Tags: perl, moose

Assuming a Moose object like this

```
package Foo;
use Moose;
has a => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Int' );
has b => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'Str' );
has c => ( is => 'rw', isa => 'HashRef' );

around [ qw(a b c) ] => sub {
    my $orig = shift;
    my $self = shift;
    return $self->$orig() unless @_;
    my $aname = ???? # meta something?
    $self->myfunction($aname, @_);
};
```

How do I set `$aname` to be the name of the attribute that is being set.  In other words, if

```
$foo->a(2)
```

I want to be able set `$aname` to `a`.

I could set an `around` for each attribute but that seems to be repetitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One method would be to use a for loop as modeled in [Moose::Manual::MethodModifiers #Wrapping multiple methods at once](https://metacpan.org/pod/Moose::Manual::MethodModifiers#Wrapping-multiple-methods-at-once):

```
for my $aname (qw(a b c)) {
    around $aname => sub {
        my $orig = shift;
        my $self = shift;
        return $self->$orig() unless @_;
        $self->myfunction( $aname, @_ );
    };
}
```

Comment: *Slaps Forehead*  Doh, Should have thought of that!  I am curious, though if there is a introspective way to determine the attribute.  I'll leave this open for a little while to see if anybody has an idea.  Thanks again!

Comment: It's definitely possible to do some introspection on the `caller` stack and figure it out, but the above method is much clearer.

Comment: @Todd You can probably do it using [Sub::Identify](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Identify).

Comment: [Sub::Util](https://metacpan.org/pod/Sub::Util) also has some tools that can help.